# Migrating SSRS Reports to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am recreating the current ssrs environment for a dev env.  I need to move the existing reporting services over to this environment. I need the reports that are deployed there to be deployed in the new dev environment.  I installed SSRS in the dev environment and set it up but I obviously don't have any of the reports or data because it's a brand new instance.

This is in SQL Server 2005 with one instance.  Can I backup and restore the prod database to the dev database and just point the Report Service to the restored database (under a different name).. and restore the key as well.

Can I do this without taking the prod database offline?

Basically I need to recreate / copy the prod DB to a dev DB in one database server / instance.

On the prod server it appears to go through SharePoint but the database connection is native.  The dev server is going through vanilla IIS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do that (backup while SSRS is active).

But before you do anything please backup the encryption keys:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157275.aspx

You should also backup (and restore) all the SSRS config files (amazing how many there are!)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155814.aspx

After the move make sure that the projects you are working on point to the dev machine (if thats where your test data is) and that when you deploy a report you deploy to the dev machine.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to go pretty smooth other than now my reports give me an error after logging in and running a search: Cannot Create a connection to data source: DynamicsAX so I'm working on figuring out that aspect.

Comment: I want to add that I can't really restore the original configs as it's not a 1:1 match of the prod server.  It looks like the prod server is running it through sharepoint while here it's just vanilla IIS.

Comment: By omitting you are going from Sharepoint to a regular install you just changed your question radically.

Comment: I didn't know I was going to sharepoint to regular until 20 minutes ago when I got access to the actual prod server.

Comment: so just downvote without any clarification?  What changes exactly?

Comment: You asked a question that I provided an extensive answer for but its irrelevent because your setup is completely different so of course instead of owning up to it you downvoted my correct answer.

Comment: I provided the information as I got it, and instead if allowing me to made any adjustments you downvoted.  On top of that I don't see how it makes your extensive answer irrelevant as the connection to the database is still native.  Maybe it still does but you could explain what's different instead of just downvoting.

Comment: It wasn't an integrated sharepoint site. It was located in a website / folder just called sharepoint but it was native.  Moving the database table over did work, a key issue was dealing with Kerberos and SPN generation.  For external users to be able to get to the reports I had to generate a SPN for the report service account and the application pool service account in IIS.  The first one is in the instructions, the application pool service account is something that didn't seem too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can export/download the existing reports from "Report Manager" URL i.e. from http://yourProdServer/Reports.

Point the reports to the new Dev environment.

Deploy the reports to the new Dev server i.e. http://yourDevServer/ReportServer.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an export option.  and on my new deserver I can't get to http://devserver/Reports it's telling me the resource can't be found

Comment: if your target reporting services is configured with Sharepoint mode than this is not the approach. This applicable to SSRS native mode only. Please mention how your source and target servers are configured (native or sharepoint mode).

Comment: On the Database setup it says Native but for Virtual Directory Server and Manager it says they are through SharePoint.  I should say the Websites are labeled as Sharepoint.

Comment: how do you access your reports in your existing system? is it from sharepoint site?

Comment: It's a link generated from Dynamics Ax.  It goes straight to the report, the link that is generated provides the report criteria (like a record number).